# Will it hurt to have a US bank account from the past if I apply to a B2 visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I used to work in the US on a H1B and had my trading account and bank accounts there for 6 years. I never closed those accounts and have been living in Canada on a PR for 8 months now but my trading account and bank account is still with the US.

I am going to apply for a B2 visa soon. Will using the same US accounts for my proof of funds hurt my chances of getting the visa?

Comment: It might. That you have PR in Canada suggests a reason to leave the US after your prospective tourist entry. On the other hand, having US dollar investment and bank accounts shows a connection to the US, and might suggest that you will overstay in the US or go underground. If you do apply for a visa, you must answer truthfully all of the questions put to you.

Comment: You might want to make sure your accounts are appropriate for a non-US-person (e.g. that they take withholding tax when required) before advertising that you still have them. I was permitted by the bank to keep a brokerage account I liked when I left the US under circumstances similar to yours only because the account owner was a US trust rather than me personally. They said that they would have been legally required to close the account otherwise.

Comment: Update: I did get the visa however my bank statements were never asked for in my interview. I told the interviewer I was going to the US to stay there for 3 months to visit my GF and they were understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Lots of Canadians have US Bank accounts. Those that lived there in the past often have investments there. As long as you can demonstrate the usual ties to Canada it is unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

No. If anything it would improve your application since you are not a broke tourist.

US is one of the biggest tax heavens in the world for foreigners. Millions of foreigners work with US institutions. You're not the only non-US person who visits US while having a US bank or broker account.